# What is the Qibla inside the Kaaba?

Tags: salat, islamic-scholar, kaabah, qiblah, mecca

Assalam o Alaikum to all my Muslim brothers,

If one were to get the opportunity to pray Salah inside the Kaaba, which direction should he face?

Comment: I've covered this in one of my two answers about kaaba.